# Why we are using coupling capacitor in AC amplifier?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

Why we are using coupling capacitor in AC amplifier?

Comment: to amplify the ac part only, but not the dc part

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 3):

Usually the output from each stage of the amplifier is a constant voltage (with respect to some reference point, which I'll call 'the ground rail') with an alternating 'signal' voltage superimposed on it. The constant voltage arises because most amplifying devices, such as transistors, need such voltages to be applied to some of their electrodes in order to work properly.

The input of the next stage of the amplifier may need a constant 'bias' voltage (as well as the alternating signal voltage. But its ideal bias voltage is unlikely to be the same as the constant voltage present in the output of the previous stage. So that the latter is not passed on to the second stage (but the alternating signal voltage *is*), capacitor coupling is used. A separate resistor arrangement is used to supply the correct bias to the second stage input (e.g. the base of a transistor).